# Get just the values without the fields queryset

Tags: python, json, django, datatables

I have this def in my views.py:

```
def listar_animais(request, pk):
vacas_no_lote = Animal.objects.filter(id_lote=pk, status=True, sexo=Sexo.F).values('id_animal', 'id_lote', 'id_raca')
return JsonResponse({ 'data' : list( vacas_no_lote )})
```

And I'm getting this return in JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id_animal": 2,
      "id_brinco": 5456,
      "id_raca": 3
    },
    {
      "id_animal": 4,
      "id_brinco": 5456,
      "id_raca": 3
    },
    {
      "id_animal": 5,
      "id_brinco": 5456,
      "id_raca": 3
    },
    {
      "id_animal": 9,
      "id_brinco": 5456,
      "id_raca": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

But I just want values, like this:

```
{
  'data': [
    ['1', '5471', 'Angus'],
    ['3', '5547', 'Nelore'],
    ['8', '6874', 'Brahman']
  ]
}
```

I need in this format because it's how will work with jQuery Datables as explained here: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.values_list()` instead of `.values()`.

Comment: It works! But, is there a way to bring, for example, the "id_raca.description" instead of getting the id number?

Comment: Yes. You can use `.values_list('id_raca__description')`. Double underscore to access attribute from the referenced object.